# Star hack not working in IE6 AND 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-6

Can somewhere help be, my star hacks arnt working in IE6 and 8 for these form elements I am trying to style? But it oddly works in ie7?

I tried adding the star infront of the class selector in general, which made it work in IE8 and 7, but stil not 6 and then made the * apply to firefox, safari, chrome etc. too which just means the star was applying to every browser which I don't need, just internet explorer.

Any help please?

```
/* FORMS */

/*SEARCH*/

#searchform .s, #searchform .but{float:left;}

#searchform .s{
background-color:rgba(128, 129, 132, 0.4);background-image: url(images/line.png);margin-bottom: 10px; border: none;  padding:10px;width: 140px;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #868686; 
}

#searchform .but
{
background-color:rgba(128, 129, 132, 0.4);  margin-bottom: 10px; border: none;  padding:10px;width: 30px;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif; font-size: 12px;font-weight: bold; color:#00ADEE;
}

/* IE HACK */

*#searchform .s{
*background-color:#C3C3C4;
}

*#searchform .but{
*background-color:#C3C3C4;
*height: 35px
}

/*FIREFOX btn HACK*/    
#searchform .but::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0
}

/* MAILING LIST */

#mc_embed_signup #mce-EMAIL, #mc_embed_signup #mc-embedded-subscribe{float:left;}

#mc_embed_signup{margin-top: 10px;  
background-image: url(images/ieblue.png); }
#mc_embed_signup #text { padding: 8px 5px 8px 8px;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif; font-size: 10px; line-height: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF;}
#mc_embed_signup .asterisk {color: #FFFFFF}
#mc_embed_signup #mce-EMAIL {background-color:rgba(0, 173, 238, 0.6);background-image: url(images/line2.png);
margin-bottom: 10px; border: none;  padding:10px;width: 158px;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF; }
#mc_embed_signup #mc-embedded-subscribe {background-color:rgba(0, 173, 238, 0.6);  margin-bottom: 10px; border: none;  padding:10px;width: 30px;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif; font-size: 12px;font-weight: bold; color:#FFFFFF;
}

/* IE HACK */
* #mc_embed_signup #mce-EMAIL{
*background-color:#60c7ee;
}
* #mc_embed_signup #mc-embedded-subscribe{
*background-color:#60c7ee;
*height: 35px
}

/*FIREFOX btn HACK*/    
#mc_embed_signup #mc-embedded-subscribe::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0
}

#hidemap{
display: none;}

/* DIRECTIONS */
#daddr #saddr{float:left;}


#saddr {background-color:rgba(128, 129, 132, 0.4);background-image: url(images/line.png);
margin-bottom: 0px; border: none;  padding:10px;width: 158px; ;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #868686;}
#saddrbut {background-color:rgba(128, 129, 132, 0.4);  margin-bottom: 0px; border: none;  padding:10px;width: 30px;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif; font-size: 12px;font-weight: bold; color:#00ADEE;
}

*#saddr{
*background-color:#C3C3C4;
}

*#saddrbut{
*background-color:#C3C3C4;
*height: 35px
}

/*FIREFOX btn HACK*/    
#saddrbut::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The star hack targets IE7 and below, which explains why it isn't working for you in IE8. I can't say why it isn't working for IE6; I thought the star hack would work for it, but since we've dropped support for IE6, I haven't had to think about it for some time, so I may not be remembering correctly.

I would like to say that using hacks like this is generally a bad idea -- nine times out of ten, if you're using a CSS hack for anything other than IE6, then you're doing something wrong. Even for IE6, it is better to use conditional comments (in fact this point applies to all versions of IE).

If you *must* use CSS hacks to target IE, I suggest looking at [this page](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/) which gives specific hacks which you can use to target any individual combination of IE versions.

If you're targetting IE8 and below, then the `\9` hack would seem to be appropriate. I would still re-iterate what I said earlier, and recommend not using hacks at all if at all possible.

Hope that helps.

[EDIT]

The reason it isn't working for you is that the star hack goes on the properties, not the selector.

So you have this:

```
*#searchform .s{
*background-color:#C3C3C4;
}
```

whereas the star hack would only want the star on the `background-color` line, not the `#searchform` selector.

[EDIT2]

More importantly, you don't actually need to use any hack here at all.

Simply specify the plain-colour fall-back version first, followed by the more advanced version, and the browsers will pick the one that works for them, according to what they support:

```
#searchform .s{
    background-color:#C3C3C4;
    background-color:rgba(128, 129, 132, 0.4);
    margin-bottom: 10px; border: none;
}
```

See -- no hacks required.  :-)

Comment: Okay, I get the point. This is only for these 3 elements so I thought a hack would be simpler than duplicating the stylesheet and ending up having to edit two stylesheets later. the \9 works with IE7 and 8 but once again not 6, I'm not sure if it's to do with the fact I am trying to style the background colour of an input feed and maybe IE6 doesn't allow that, any ideas?

Comment: @Amy - quite possibly that is the reason. But whatever, you don't actually need a hack here at all; just specify the plain colour version first followed by the rgba version, and it'll just work in all browsers according to what they support. (I'll edit the answer to reflect that point)

Comment: Hmm, I don't have a copy of IE6 to test it for you, but I'm fairly sure it does support background colors on input fields. Check that you're not in quirks mode (but I doubt it, as this would have given you other issues). I would suggest creating a test page which just demonstrates this specific issue in IE6 (create a basic page with just that field, and style it just with the plain color without any hacks etc). If it still mis-behaves, try asking about it here as a new question. If it works, try adding the other stuff around it until it breaks, to see if you can isolate what's causing it.

Answer (score 1):

I've read a bit on those css-hacks, and boy are they messy! There is a good reference on
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter) available.

I would advice you  to use conditional comments in your html for IE-styling though. It keeps all your IE-specific styling in a seperate file:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <link href="style-ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 8]>
  <link href="style-below-ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

This is a complete guide about conditional comments:
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: when i try this, ie never uses it?

Comment: It should be "IE 8", not "IE8".

Comment: Thanks, changed that. @Amy make sure the stylesheet href is pointing to the right css-file.